# Is there a way i can assign each function parameter to a specific array value using a for loop?

Tags: c++, arrays

so I have a Vector.h file that contains:

```
private:
 double arr[SIZE];
public:
 static const int SIZE = 3;
 Vector();
 Vector(double,double,double);
```

and in my Vector.cpp I have:

```
Vector::Vector()
{
  for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    components[i] = 0.0;
  }
}
```

So i assigned each value to the array to 0 but what I was curious about is how can do do the same thing using function parameters:

```
Vector::Vector(double x , double y, double, z)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
  {
    /* code ? */
  }
}
```

How would i assign each double x , y , z to the array index 0 , 1 , 2 so it would be components[0] = x, components[1] = y, components[2] = z ?

Comment: A loop isn’t really designed for that

Comment: Either set your `components` manually, or pass in an array of length 3 that contains [x,y,z] which you can then iterate over.

Comment: *"How would i assign each double x , y , z to the array index 0 , 1 , 2 so it would be components[0] = x, components[1] = y, components[2] = z ?"* -- you mean to get the result of `components[0] = x;` `components[1] = y;` `components[2] = z;` but by using something needlessly more complex? *(If you intended the number of parameters to be variable, that would be a different situation. It's also not what you asked.)*

Answer (score 0):

If you add a constructor that takes a single [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) parameter then you an iterate that with a [ranged for loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Here's a quick proof-of-concept snippet that should demonstrate what I'm talking about (please note that there is no range checking in this code!):

```
#include <initializer_list>

void foo (std::initializer_list <double> il)
{
    double arr [3];
    int i = 0;
    for (double d : il)
        arr [i++] = d;
}

int main ()
{
    foo ({1, 2, 3});
}
```

[Live demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZuB0NAU4nZjwU1WC)